# What does for(int i : x) do?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am new to Java. I was reading someone's solution to a question and I encountered this:

```
        int[] ps = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            ps[i] = input.nextInt();

        int[] counts = new int[1005];
        for (int p : ps)
            counts[p]++;
```

What do the last two lines do?

Comment: The variable `p` ranges over the array `ps`. You can play around with it a little to see how it works, e.g. print the value of `p` in the loop.

Comment: this is enhanced for loop. p is a local variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a *for-each loop*. It sets `p` to the first element of `ps`, then runs the loop body. Then it sets `p` to the second element of `ps`, then runs the loop body. And so on.

It's approximately short for:

```
for(int k = 0; k < ps.length; k++)
{
    int p = ps[k];
    counts[p]++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## For-each loop (Advanced or Enhanced For loop):

> The for-each loop introduced in Java5. It is mainly used to traverse
> array or collection elements. The advantage of for-each loop is that
> it eliminates the possibility of bugs and makes the code more
> readable.

Syntax

```
for(data_type variable : array | collection){}
```

Source :[Java For Each Loop](http://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loop)

In your case this loop is iterating the `Array`

Equivalent Code without For Each Loop

```
for (int i=0;i<ps.length;i++){
int p=ps[i];
counts[p]++;
}
```

Comment: `p` is not the index its the elements of array `ps`

Comment: @singhakash , I was trying to explain him For-Each loop, how counter is incremented , not going on logical explaination ,still editing it !!

Answer (score 0):

That's a for loop. `for (int p : ps)` iterates over ints in the `ps` int array

Answer (score 0):

The line is iterating over each index of array an taking out its value in a sequence in a `p` varable.You can check by

```
for (int p : ps){            // if ps is {1,2,3}
   System.out.print(p+" ");  // it will print 1 2 3
   counts[p]++;
}
```